# ng-click is not working for default option in select box

Tags: angularjs

I have added

```
<select ng-model="some_value"
                    ng-options="item.tt  for item in  data" ng-change="fnCall()" style="width: 85%" id="first">
                    <option value="" ng-click="fnCall()">--Select Value--/option>
            </select>
```

But on click of select value(default option), the function is not called, any idea?

Comment: Your intent is not clear. As the answer below states, there is no click event on an Option, but you can hook into the change event. What is your reason for wanting to handle a click on the default option?

Comment: Yes, i agree with that. By any way(on change or onclick) how can fire an function, even the value already selected.

Comment: The way a select element works is that if you choose the same value again - it does not change, no change event is fired. What I don't understand is the purpose of your requirement - _Why_ do you need an event to tell you that someone has chosen the already selected default option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `option` tag doesn't have a click event (at least not in the way you're trying to use it), only the `select` element does.

Stick with `ng-change`, it should be called with a default value (null) if the default option is selected.

**Update**:

To achieve what you want, either bind a `span/h4/any-element` with the text "Select a value" to the model with an `ng-hide="some_value"`. Or, use `fnCall(some_value)` to display an alert.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/13105/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="test" ng-change="fnCall(test)" ng-options="val for val in values">
        <option value="">Select a value</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

-

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);   

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.values = [1, 2, 3]
    $scope.fnCall = function (val) {
        if (!val) {
            alert('Please select a value');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but i need on click of default value, need to show alert("select value")

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response, i tried as you said, but not working, do you have any working example?